# How do I reverse referenced documents across two collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a `person` collection with documents like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('64103dd44c7b1355e4812e87'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Brian',
teams: [
    ObjectId('62f63b38e6a6cbb9a58c58c4'),
    ObjectId('64219e4eb5924e070a23f846')
]
```

---

```
    _id: ObjectId('642ad97d0c945ff64f2a5f4c'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Marc',
teams: [
    ObjectId('64219e4eb5924e070a23f846')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64269d6c38364df7ca902d75'),
sport: 'Basketball',
name: 'Francis',
teams: [
    ObjectId('641453c9adc10762db6997cb'),
    ObjectId('64269ebc38364df7ca902e17')
]
```

Then I have this `teams` collection with documents like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('62f63b38e6a6cbb9a58c58c4'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Team A',
persons: [
    ObjectId('642ada46f785be5eb0042f63')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64219e4eb5924e070a23f846'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Team B',
persons: [
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('62f3a57bcc852536a665b179'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Team C',
persons: [
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('641453c9adc10762db6997cb'),
sport: 'Basketball',
name: 'Team D',
persons: [
    ObjectId('642ada848b8c7b48102c3cb4')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64269ebc38364df7ca902e17'),
sport: 'Basketball',
name: 'Team E',
persons: [
    ObjectId('642ada95f8f190e02582e10d')
]
```

Right now my teams are referenced in the person documents, and I'm trying to create a script that basically reverses it, so that the persons are referenced in the team documents instead.

Keep in mind that there is already some existing references in the team documents which should be kept. And also the each migration should not be done across sports: A person that has the sport 'football' should not be migrated to a team that is other than 'football' for example..

The result should look like this:

## person

```
_id: ObjectId('64103dd44c7b1355e4812e87'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Brian'
```

---

```
    _id: ObjectId('642ad97d0c945ff64f2a5f4c'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Marc'
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64269d6c38364df7ca902d75'),
sport: 'Basketball',
name: 'Francis'
```

## team

```
_id: ObjectId('62f63b38e6a6cbb9a58c58c4'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Team A',
persons: [
    ObjectId('62f641ae84f995495a0f567f')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64219e4eb5924e070a23f846'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Team B',
persons: [
    ObjectId('642ada46f785be5eb0042f63'),
    ObjectId('64103dd44c7b1355e4812e87'),
    ObjectId('642ad97d0c945ff64f2a5f4c')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('62f3a57bcc852536a665b179'),
sport: 'Football',
name: 'Team C',
persons: [
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('641453c9adc10762db6997cb'),
sport: 'Basketball',
name: 'Team D',
persons: [
    ObjectId('642ada848b8c7b48102c3cb4'),
    ObjectId('64269d6c38364df7ca902d75')
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64269ebc38364df7ca902e17'),
sport: 'Basketball',
name: 'Team E',
persons: [
    ObjectId('642ada95f8f190e02582e10d'),
    ObjectId('64269d6c38364df7ca902d75')
]
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `teams` collection you can run a query like:

```
db.teams.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "persons",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "teams",
      pipeline: [{$project: {_id: 1}}],
      as: "moreP"
  }},
  {$project: {
      persons: {$concatArrays: [
          "$persons",
          {$map: {
              input: "$moreP",
              in: "$$this._id"
          }}
      ]},
      name: 1,
      sport: 1
  }},
  {$merge: {into: "teams"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sagaZdLpNNg)

**Afterwards**:
You can update the `persons` collection to unset the `teams` key:

```
db.persons.updateMany({}, {$unset: {teams: ""}})
```

Comment: In the first aggregation, is `name: 1, sport: 1` necessary? If I only project persons, will it not only merge the `persons` field and leave the two other fields as they are?

Comment: something like this: `{ into: "teams", on: "_id", whenMatched: "merge" }`

Comment: Since `persons` is already a field on the existing document, you need to test it. It may work.